# Using `dependent induction` tactic to keep information while doing induction

Tags: coq, induction, coq-tactic

I have just run into the issue of the Coq `induction` discarding information about constructed terms while reading a proof from [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Equiv.html).

The authors used something like:

```
remember (WHILE b DO c END) as cw eqn:Heqcw.
```

to rewrite a hypothesis `H` before the actual induction `induction H`. I really don't like the idea of having to introduce a trivial equality as it looks like black magic.

Some search here in SO shows that actually the `remember` trick is necessary. One answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4899467/683218), however, points out that the new `dependent induction` can be used to avoid the `remember` trick. This is nice, but the `dependent induction` itself now seems a bit magical.

I have a hard time trying to understand how `dependent induction` works. The [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic78) gives an example where `dependent induction` is required:

```
Lemma le_minus : forall n:nat, n < 1 -> n = 0.
```

I can verify how `induction` fails and `dependent induction` works in this case. But I can't use the `remember` trick to replicate the `dependent induction` result.

What I tried so far to mimic the `remember` trick is:

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.

Lemma le_minus : forall n:nat, n < 1 -> n = 0.
intros n H. (* dependent induction H works*) 
remember (n < 1) as H0. induction H.
```

But this doesn't work. Anyone can explain how `dependent induction` works here in terms of the `remember`-ing?

Comment: As indicated in the documentation, dependent induction is defined in Coq.Program.Equality. You can [dig through its guts](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Program.Equality.html) to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.

Lemma le_minus : forall n:nat, n < 1 -> n = 0.
Proof.
intros n H.
remember 1 as m in H. induction H.
- inversion Heqm. reflexivity.
- inversion Heqm. subst m.
  inversion H.
Qed.
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522477/1633770), the problem is that Coq cannot keep track of the shape of terms that appear in the type of the thing you are doing induction on. In other words, doing induction over the "less than" relation instructs Coq to try to prove something about a generic upper bound, as opposed to the specific one you're considering (1).

Notice that it is always possible to prove such goals without `remember` or `dependent induction`, by generalizing your result a little bit:

```
Lemma le_minus_aux :
  forall n m, n < m ->
    match m with
    | 1 => n = 0
    | _ => True
    end.
Proof.
intros n m H. destruct H.
- destruct n; trivial.
- destruct H; trivial.
Qed.

Lemma le_minus : forall n, n < 1 -> n = 0.
Proof.
intros n H.
apply (le_minus_aux n 1 H).
Qed.
```